# SQL Generated From LINQ Query against Telerik ORM

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, telerik, telerik-open-access

I am experiencing some confusion on the SQL generated from a fairly standard LINQ query using a LEFT OUTER JOIN. The query is against the Free Telerik Open Access/Data Access product.

I wrote the following LINQ ...

```
01.var sessionQ = from sessionHdr in headersQ
02.   join sessionBody in bodyQ on
03.        sessionHdr.ID equals sessionBody.ID into sessionList
04.   from sessionJSON in sessionList.DefaultIfEmpty()
05.   where sessionHdr.Format == 13
06. 
07.   select new WITransmitsVP
08.   {
09.      ...
10.   };
```

Using this LINQ syntax for an OUTER JOIN I was expecting the SQL (ORACLE) generated to look something like the following ...

```
1.SELECT
2.    ...
3. 
4.FROM "XFEVP"."WI_TRANSMITS_VP" a
5.    INNER JOIN "XFEVP"."WI_TRANSMITS_VP_MSG" b ON
6.      a."MESSAGE_ID" = b."MESSAGE_ID"
7.WHERE a."MESSAGE_ID" = 60412762;
```

But instead when I log the output I am seeing  ...

```
01.SELECT
02.    ...
03. 
04.FROM "XFEVP"."WI_TRANSMITS_VP" a
05.WHERE a."MESSAGE_ID" = :p0                                      
06.ORDER BY COL1 
07. 
08.SELECT
09.    ...
10. 
11.FROM "XFEVP"."WI_TRANSMITS_VP_MSG" a
12.ORDER BY COL1
```

Instead of a single SELECT with OUTER JOIN I am seeing two entirely separate SELECT statements. Since the each table contains MILLIONS of records and presumably ALL the contents of the second table are being queried rather than just those joined to the results of the first SELECT statement the component making the call eventually crashes due to memory issues after many many minutes of latency.

Why am I not getting a actual JOIN statement in the generated SQL? Is there a workaround a fix or am I simply doing something wrong?

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to EVK for providing the answer. It turns out that the problem was in the way I was defining the IQueryables. I swapped out the IQueryables with references to the DBContext collections instead ...

```
01.var sessionQ = from sessionHdr in DBContext.SessionHeaders
02.   join sessionBody in DBContext.SessionBodies on
03.        sessionHdr.ID equals sessionBody.ID into sessionList
04.   from sessionJSON in sessionList.DefaultIfEmpty()
05.   where sessionHdr.Format == 13
06. 
07.   select new WITransmitsVP
08.   {
09.      ...
10.   };
```

This resulted in the following generated SQL ...

```
SELECT 

    ...

FROM "XFEVP"."WI_TRANSMITS_VP" a 
    LEFT JOIN "XFEVP"."WI_TRANSMITS_VP_MSG" b ON 
        (a."MESSAGE_ID" = b."MESSAGE_ID") 
WHERE a."FORMAT" = :p0
```

Comment: And how headersQ and bodyQ defined?

Comment: headersQ and bodyQ are IQueryable<T>

Comment: What will happen if you replace those queries with just table definitions? I mean just context.TableName.

Comment: Same thing ... in fact the bodyQ is nothing more than a reference to DBContext.WiTransmitsVPMessages ... which returns an IQueryable from the ORM context.

Comment: I take that back!! I just tweaked the query a bit and am now seeing the LEFT JOIN appear as I would expect ... my filter is not being applied but that may be another post.

Comment: Could you post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as the answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that `headersQ` and `bodyQ` represent some relatively complex query (maybe not for you, but for ORM you use), and so it has some troubles building single query which combines them. So instead of throwing some exception it does something bad - pulles both query results into memory and combines them there.

Comment: I have added more detail on the implementation of the solution to the OP. Thanks!!